# информации о фильмах на новой странице

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите по этому проекту кое что (https://github.com/annbin000/cinema_mvc)

есть вложенные темплейты с выгрузкой с бд как на скрине, подскажите как выгрузитьб инфу с бд о этих фильмах и при нажатии открывать в новой странице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть модель
/app/Models/Films.php
в которой я записала методы гет сет на каждое поле.

Дальше есть сервис
app/Services/FilmService.php
В нем я выбираю все информацию о фильмах

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    select films.*
    from films
    where films.id = :id
SQL;
```

После чего идет код с подключением к бд и получении по айди велью и тд.

Дальше есть контроллер 
app/Controllers/FilmController.php
и в нем такой метод

```
public function execute()
{
    $filmService = new FilmService();
    $view = new View();
    $result = $view->show(Films::class);
    return $result;
}
```

После чего передаю все во вьюху
app/Views/Film.php

```
class Film extends AbstractBlock implements ViewInterface
{
    protected function getVars(): array
    {
        $filmService = new FilmService();
        return [
            'films' => $filmService->findOneFilm()
        ];
    }
}
```

После чего есть темплейт
templates/film.phtml

В котором я по идее должна выгрузить инфу о фильме а в темплейте 
templates/comeout.phtml
передать ссылку на этот фильм, подскажите как это сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: $filmService->findOneFilm() находит один фильм. значит нужно во вьюхе в цикле перебрать его элементы и вывести их с помощью echo.

Comment: так как у вас один фильм, то можно даже и без цикла вывести во вью его данные. <?=$films['name']?> например. Только я бы изменил переменную на $film, так как вы получаете один фильм, а не несколько в app/Views/Film.php

Comment: @Woleks облема больше в том, что б при нажатии на фильм меня редиректнуло на страницу с информацией о фильмах

Comment: @Woleks  у меня проблема в том, что я делаю по примеру своего кода ранее, то не выходит ибо в моем урле `https://cinema.com/cinema/` все работает на этом роуте и когда приходятданные о фильме то в нетьворке видно пакет с названием ComeOut?id=1, я пыталась сделать что то подобное но при нажатии на ссылку всегда просто обновляет страницу переходя на информацию, что там и была

Comment: Какой адрес у страницы с одним фльмом?

Comment: @Woleks да в том и проблема, я не могу понять как ему задать адрес

Comment: @Woleks ренерация урла идет в папке контроллера, файл dispacher, там роут запроса ненерируется методом имени класса к которому добавляет Controller и с него уже получает информацию, вроле бы так это работает, нашла такой пример в инетике

Comment: https://github.com/annbin000/cinema_mvc/blob/master/config/routes.php для начала нужно здесь добавить новый роут

Comment: плюс нужен метод, который будет парсить урл и доставать из урл название контроллера, метода в контроллере, затем создавать объект класса контроллера и вызывать метод. А уже сам метод будет делать то, что вам нужно, например выводить информацию о фильме во вью. Например http://cinema.com/Film/show/23 - Film( контроллер), show(метод в контроллере Film), id - это айдишник фильма.

Comment: @Woleks я не могу на том же роуте доставать все? у меня уже есть парсер url `app/Controllers/Dispatcher.php`

Comment: @Woleks не могли бы вы посмотреть немного подробнее работу кода, я недавно начала писать на php и еще много чего плохо дается, я залила базу данных в гит реп, на случий если вы согласитесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все почти сделанно, **дальнейший код будет предоставлен на основе твоего**, вообще способ немного запутьанный.

С Сервисом `FilmService.php` все норм, так и оставим.
В `FilmController.php`
в принципе все верно, но я вижу ты пыталась сделать на примере своего кода из `CinemaController.php`, но `ComeOutController.php` тебе больше поможет

```
public function execute() {
    $view = new Film();
    $result = $view->render();

    return $result;
}
```

show там не нужна ибо ты уже переписала все на render. С контроллером все, если все хорошо, то при наведении на `new Film();` у тебя должно редиректнуть на твою вьюху. К ней и перейдем.
Там на примере так же твоего кода нужно чет такое.

```
class Film extends AbstractBlock implements ViewInterface
{
    private $id;

    public function setFilm(int $id): Film {

        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function getVars(): array
    {
        $id = $this->id ?? (int) $_GET['id'];
        $filmService = new FilmService();

        $temp = $filmService->findOneFilm($id);
        return [
            'film' => $filmService->findOneFilm($id)
        ];
    }
}
```

В самом темплейте фильма поправь вот так.

```
<?php /** @var \App\Models\Films $film */ ?>
<ul>
    <li>Имя: <?= $film->getName() ?></li>
</ul>


а в темплейте comeout сделай 
<?php /** @var \App\Models\Films[] $comeOut */ ?>
<?php foreach ($comeOut as $film): ?>
    <li><a href="<?= "film/?id=" . $film->getId() ?>"><?= $film->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Теперь, по идее должно по нажатию переходить на урл типа 
https://site.com/film/?id=1
Ну и там теперь в дебагере посмотри какие у тебя еще поля приходят и добавь их для полноценной картины о фильме.